# Optimize query within sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following algorithm

```
For R = FirstRowDBABACUS To LastRowDBABACUS ' R = Remboursement
    LastInterestDate = ""
    Do While Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value <> 0
        For Inte = FirstRowDBABACUS To LastRowDBABACUS
            'On commence par l'intérêt
            If Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 3).Value <= DateArrete Then
                LastInterestDate = "R" & Inte & "C" & 3
                If Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8).Value <> 0 Then
                    If Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value > Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8).Value Then
                        'Modification du montant de Remboursement residuel
                        Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value = Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value - Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8)
                        Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 12).Value = Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 8).Value
                        Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8).Value = 0
                    Else
                        'Le montant ne suffit pas pour les intérêts
                        Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 12).Value = Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 12).Value + Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value
                        Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8).Value = Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 8).Value - Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value
                        Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
                'Principal s'il reste quelque chose
                If Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value <> 0 Then
                    If Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9) <> 0 Then
                        If Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value > Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9).Value Then
                            'Modification du montant de Remboursement residuel
                            Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value = Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value - Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9)
                            Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 11).Value = Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 9).Value
                            Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9).Value = 0
                        Else
                            'Le montant ne suffit pas pour le remboursmeent du principal
                            Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 11).Value = Sheets(RapproSheetName).Cells(Inte, 11).Value + Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value
                            Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9).Value = Sheets("CI").Cells(Inte, 9).Value - Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value
                            Sheets("CI").Cells(R, 10).Value = 0
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Else

            End If
        Next Inte
```

I am trying to write a code sql , it takes too long time and wrong results.

```
>   declare @RefAbacus as nvarchar(100)
>     set @RefAbacus ='002-00000001'
>     SELECT
>       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>       ORDER BY [RefAbacus]),
>       * INTO #CI
>     FROM [CI]
>     WHERE [RefAbacus] = @RefAbacus
>     order by date, TypeOperation
>     SELECT
>       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
>       ORDER BY [RefAbacus]),
>       * INTO #DBRapproEchRemb
>     FROM [DBTmpRapproEchRemb]
>     WHERE [RefAbacus] =@RefAbacus
>     order by date, TypeOperation
>     
>     CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_1 on #CI ([RefAbacus], RowNum)
>     CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_2 on #DBRapproEchRemb ([RefAbacus], RowNum)
>     --declaration des variables
>     DECLARE @MaxRownum int
>     SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT
>       MAX(RowNum)
>     FROM #CI) -----------------------
>     DECLARE @MinRownum int
>     SET @MinRownum = (SELECT
>       MIN(RowNum)
>     FROM #CI)
>     
>     DECLARE @FR int;
>     DECLARE @LR int;
>     DECLARE @inte int;
>     DECLARE @R int;
>     DECLARE @remboursement AS float
>     DECLARE @LastInterestDate AS nvarchar(50);
>     DECLARE @i int;
>     DECLARE @TolerancePart int;
>     
>     SET @FR = @MinRownum
>     SET @LR = @MaxRownum
>     SET @TolerancePart = 5;
>     ----------------------------------------------------
>     
>     SET @R = (SELECT
>       MIN(RowNum)
>     FROM #CI)
>     SET @inte = (SELECT
>       MIN(RowNum)
>     FROM #CI)
>     
>     
>           WHILE @R <= @MaxRownum
>               BEGIN
>               
>                   while  (SELECT [Remboursement] FROM #CI WHERE RowNum = @R ) <>0  and   (SELECT [Remboursement] FROM #CI WHERE RowNum = @R ) IS NOT
> NULL
>                   begin
>                   SET @LastInterestDate = ''
>                   SET @inte = (SELECT
>                     MIN(RowNum)
>                   FROM #CI)-1
>                       WHILE @inte <= @MaxRownum
>                           BEGIN -- run your operation here
>                       --print @inte
>                           -- Condition 1
>                               SET @inte = @inte + 1;
>                           IF (SELECT Date FROM #CI WHERE RowNum = @inte)<= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
>     
>                               BEGIN
>                               SET @LastInterestDate = 'R' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @inte) + 'C3'
>     
>                               -- Condition 2
>                               IF ((SELECT EchInteret FROM #CI
>                               WHERE RowNum = @inte) <> 0)
>                                   BEGIN
>                           
>                                   -- Condition 3 
>                                   IF ((SELECT [Remboursement] FROM #CI 
>                                   WHERE RowNum = @R) > (SELECT EchInteret FROM #CI
>                                   WHERE RowNum = @inte))
>                                       BEGIN ---------------------------------------
>                                       -- Update 1
>                                       print 'Update 1'
>                                       UPDATE #CI
>                                       SET [Remboursement] = R.[Remboursement] - isnull(INTE.EchInteret,0)
>                                       FROM (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE INNER JOIN (SELECT  * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @R) R
>                                       ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R; 
>                               
>                                       -- Update 2
>                                       UPDATE #CI
>                                       SET EchInteret = 0
>                                       FROM (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE INNER JOIN (SELECT  * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @R) R ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                       WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte; 
>                                   
>                                       UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
>                                       SET [PartEnInterêt] = isnull(EchInteret,0)
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte;
>     
>     
>                                       --SET @inte = @inte + 1;
>                                       END
>                                       ELSE -------------------------
>                                       -- Update 3
>                                       BEGIN
>     
>                                       UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
>                                       SET [PartEnInterêt] = isnull(INTE.[PartEnInterêt],0) + R.Remboursement
>                                       FROM (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @R) R
>                                       INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #DBRapproEchRemb
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                       WHERE #DBRapproEchRemb.RowNum = @inte;
>     
>     
>                                       UPDATE #CI
>                                       SET EchInteret = isnull(INTE.EchInteret,0) - R.Remboursement
>                                       FROM (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @R) R INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                       WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte;
>     
>                                       print 'ok'
>                                       UPDATE #CI
>                                       SET Remboursement = 0
>                                       WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R;
>     
>                                       --------------------------------------------
>                                       BREAK
>                                       END
>                                   END
>     
>                                   -- Condition 4 
>                                   IF ((SELECT [Remboursement]FROM #CI
>                                   WHERE RowNum = @R) <> 0)
>     
>                                   BEGIN
>                                   -- Condition 5
>                                   IF ((SELECT EchPrincial FROM #CI
>                                   WHERE RowNum = @inte) <> 0)
>     
>                                       BEGIN
>                                   
>                                       -- Condition 6
>                                       IF ((SELECT [Remboursement] FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @R) > (SELECT EchPrincial FROM #CI
>                                       WHERE RowNum = @inte))
>     
>                                           -- Update 4
>     
>                                           BEGIN
>                                           ----------------------------
>                                           
>                                           UPDATE #CI
>                                           SET [Remboursement] = R.[Remboursement] - isnull(INTE.EchPrincial,0)
>                                           FROM (SELECT*FROM #CI
>                                           WHERE RowNum = @inte) INTE INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                           WHERE RowNum = @R) R ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                           WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R;
>                                       
>                                           UPDATE #DBRapproEchRemb
>                                           SET PartEnPrincipal =isnull( EchPrincial,0)
>                                           WHERE RowNum = @inte;
>     
>     
>                                           UPDATE #CI
>                                           SET EchPrincial = 0
>                                           WHERE #CI.RowNum = @inte;
>                                           print' avant break'
>     
>                                           END
>                                           -----------
>                                       ELSE
>                                           -- Update 5
>                                           BEGIN
>                                       
>     
>                                           UPDATE INTE
>                                           SET PartEnPrincipal = isnull(inte.PartEnPrincipal,0) + R.Remboursement
>                                           FROM (SELECT * from #DBRapproEchRemb 
>                                            WHERE RowNum = @inte)INTE INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                           WHERE RowNum = @R) R ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                           WHERE INTE.RowNum = @inte;
>     
>     
>                                           UPDATE INTE
>                                           SET EchPrincial = inte.EchPrincial + R.Remboursement
>                                           FROM #CI
>                                           INTE INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM #CI
>                                           WHERE RowNum = @R) R ON R.RefAbacus = INTE.RefAbacus
>                                           WHERE INTE.RowNum = @inte;
>     
>     
>                                           UPDATE #CI
>                                           SET Remboursement = 0
>                                           WHERE #CI.RowNum = @R;
>                                           print 'apres break'
>                                           
>                                           BREAK
>                                           END
>                                       END
>     
>                               END
>     
>                           END
>                   
>                           end
>     
>               END
>                   SET @R = @R + 1;
>           END
```

.                                                                               .                                                                              .

Comment: Looping is horribly inefficient, and nested loops are just awful. By my count I see loops nested three deep in here. No idea what this code is trying to do but it could definitely be rewritten as just a couple of set based updates instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: @SeanLange PLEASE COULD YOU HELP ME ?

Comment: Be more specific, read guide how to write the good question

Comment: If you want some help here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

First thing you'll want to do is get your SQL to get the correct results. There's no point in optimizing something that does not produce correct results. The unfortunate news here is that we can't really help you with specific optimizations until you have done this, because we need to know what the correct query looks like.

Once you have done that, the next step is to look into the execution plan and see what your query is doing. You'll want to figure out what part of your query is the most expensive part, and start optimizing that part first. Good tools will show you not only each piece of the plan, but how long those pieces take relative to the rest of the plan. If the query or batch of queries has multiple different statements inside of it, it should also show you which statements are the most expensive. If you're using SQL Server, the SQL Server Management Studio tools ship with an acceptable query plan viewer that provides this kind of information, and can even help with suggesting indexes if you're missing them. For example, if you're table scanning (fetching all of or a large segment of) a table will millions of rows just to find a few values, that will cause less-than-desirable performance. Or, if you're doing a sort on a very large dataset, that can also cause bad performance. Your query is explicitly looping, as well. If it's looping on a large set of rows, that will be expensive. If you can try to get rid of the explicit looping in favor of set based operations, the query optimizer may be able to simplify some of your steps and speed things up tremendously. But this is all speculation, because I don't have enough information to help you at this point.

Beyond that, though, unless we know the working query (the one that produces the correct results), the specific SQL database you're working with, what your schema looks like, and the size of your various tables, it won't be easy for us to help you with specific advice.